# Align the center of an image to the bottom of the screen

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I was wondering what would be the easiest way to align the vertical center of an image to the bottom of the screen in android. It doesn't seem like it should be that hard, but I can't seem to find anything with an answer to this.

Comment: if the image height is known just give it negative margin equal half of the height, and align it to bottom

Comment: There's 100s of answers for this. If you're in a `RelativeLayout` use  `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` and `android:layout_centerInParent="true"`. If this doesn't answer your question, please post some code. You should always post some code, even if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a FrameLayout and position the ImageView at the Bottom center of it.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom" />
</FrameLayout>
```